# csh startup scripts

Tags: shell, csh

I know that csh has a lot of start-up files (.login, .cshrc, etc.). The problem is that I'm starting a new csh terminal and I'm seeing a lot of non-standard (not the standard ones like $HOME, $SHELL, etc.) environment variables set at start-up that I didn't set in any of my start-up scripts. Is there a way to figure out the sequence of files that get sourced at start-up in my current session. If not, is there even a facility that tells which script sets some environment variable given the variable's name?

Comment: `man csh`. some shell man pages do a pretty go job of defining where the system wide startfiles are. usually `/usr/local/...` Good luck.

Comment: [sysdig](https://github.com/draios/sysdig) is your friend for full-system monitoring. Note that these aren't necessarily set by your shell at all -- environment variables can also be set by PAM modules and the like.

Comment: That said, this is arguably off-topic here; it would be more clearly in-scope at [unix.se].

Answer (score 2):

As mention Few options can help you. Together with "strace", they can help you identify which command file contributes

- The '-l' mode will force "login" mode
- The '-i' mdoe will force "interactive" mode
- The '-V' will force verbose.

You can use the following to check startup sequence for the 4 combinations of login/interactive:

```
strace -eopen,close csh -V       -c "exit
strace -eopen,close csh -V -i    -c "exit"
strace -eopen,close csh -V -l    -c "exit"
strace -eopen,close csh -V -i -l -c "exit"
```

While this does not explicitly show which file contribute the environment variables, it's should provide you with good leads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the system-wide start-up files. Start with:

/etc/profile

which you may find then calls:
/etc/{the system-wide shell setup you are using} e.g. /etc/csh

Then your own profile is called:

~/.profile

which you may find then in turn calls your personal shell setup, e.g.  ~/.csh

Comment: And as I said before in my comments that have mysteriously been deleted by someone: when my answer was posted *over a decade ago* that was the setup in the default csh distro that I was using (probably some old Solaris)...

Comment: Edits made. Cheers.